# Protractor: How to deal with application redirecting to external login app with alert box

Tags: typescript, selenium, protractor

I've set up protractor with typescript for my project and am trying to write a simple test where it takes you to the home page of my application and expects the title to be 'dashboard'. The problem is my application uses Pingfed for authentication so it redirects to the external login page and pops up a javascript alert box on that page. 
I have in my steps:

```
Given(/^I am on the home page$/, {timeout: 10000}, async () => {
  await page.navigateTo();
});
```

where `page.navigateTo()` calls the

```
browser.driver.get("http://localhost....");
```

It goes to the page, then navigates to the external login and pops up the alert box. Not sure what I'm supposed to do in order to handle this redirection and enter username and password in the alert box.

I've tried letting the browser sleep and then switching to the alert box to send keys. But none of this has worked, am I missing some function I need to call to detect the redirection then switch to the alert box?

Answer (score 1):

**FIRST APPROACH:**
would be to see if the window you see it's an iframe. If it is an iframe you have to switch on it, insert your data and then go back to the main page.

**SECOND APPROACH:**
would be to redirect yourself immediately to the login link by this: https://YOUR_DESIRED_USERNAME:YOUR_DESIRED_PASSOWORD@localhost:...

You have to insert the above link inside the get() method like this:

```
browser.driver.get("https://YOUR_DESIRED_USERNAME:YOUR_DESIRED_PASSOWORD@localhost:...");
// Instead of https, you can use your own protocol.
```

**THIRD APPROACH:**
[image]

You can navigate yourself in this link in order to see how a switch to alert logic works: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver_exports_TargetLocator.html

Inside there you will see that you can have this code inserted in order to locate your alert and insert on it:

```
browser.driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

***NOTE**: If you are going to be inside an Angular platform you have to insert this to your code too (at the beginning of your script):

```
browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true); // only for Angular websites
```

If you are going to be inside the alert then you will have the opportunity to insert your data normally without any patent.

Comment: `browser.ignoreSynchronization` is now deprecated, use `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);` instead.